# -Denable-debug-rules=true not giving out statistics

Tags: graphdb

I'm giving the flag -Denable-debug-rules, which the documentation says should print something to a log at least every 5 minutes, according to http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/rules-optimisations.html

Unfortunately it's not, and I need to figure out why inferencing is taking so long.

Help?

The specific files is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/pr.owl and I'm using owl2-rl-optimized

Version graphdb-ee-6.3.1

Comment: Not means: Nothing to the logs in an hour.

Comment: The file has ~ 9m statements, mostly class definitions and annotation. It takes about 5 minutes to load using no inference. I am trying this both with triggering reinfer within the graphdb interface as well as using loadrdf.

Comment: Command line: java -Xmx10g -Dinfo.aduna.platform.appdata.basedir=/triplestores/aduna -DentityExpansionLimit=10000000 -Denable-debug-rules=true  -cp <...> -Dlru.cache.type=lockfree -Dowlim-license=<...> -Dpool.size=4 -Dgraphdb.home.data=/triplestores/aduna/ -Dinfer.pool.size=4 LoadRDF /Volumes/trips/pro/pro.ttl fullyparallel /Volumes/trips/pro/pro_reasoned.owl

Answer (score 1):

An exchange with GraphDB tech support clarified that the built-in rule sets can not be monitored. To effectively monitor them, copy into a new file and add that file as a ruleset following http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/reasoning.html#operations-on-rulesets